# Libzip: How do I zip a folder that has files within?

Tags: c, libzip

I am trying to find out a way to zip a folder with files inside it with libzip. To clear things a bit, I technically can zip it, the problem is, when I try to unzip it with libzip as well, it crashes. Part of the reason is, I believe, the fact that I use:

```
 zip_file_add(archive, file, s, ZIP_FL_OVERWRITE)
```

Where `file` is basically the small path from the folder to the file, not just the file name. This way, I can archive the folder with all the files within. But I guess that is why it crashes, since for archiving a folder, there is `zip_dir_add()`, but I can't find a productive way to use both of them. I can use them to add both the folder and the file into the archive, but it won't be file inside the folder, just file and folder.

The fun thing is, if I archive that folder with libzip using `zip_file_add()` as above, even though it crashes when I unzip it with libzip, it doesn't when I unzip it with Ark (from KDE). But if I zip that folder with Ark, then the unzip with libzip works.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not strictly necessary to use `zip_dir_add()` unless you want to create an empty directory in the archive. But it is also fine to use it if you are also going to be putting files inside the directory. This is done using `zip_file_add()` and passing as the `name` parameter the full path as a relative path from the root of the archive.

E.g. (with error checking omitted)

```
zip_dir_add(archive, "Directory 1", ZIP_FL_ENC_UTF_8);
...
zip_file_add(archive, "Directory 1/novel.txt", s, ZIP_FL_OVERWRITE | ZIP_FL_ENC_UTF_8);
```

You could also compare your code with https://gist.github.com/clalancette/bb5069a09c609e2d33c9858fcc6e170e

If it is crashing when unzipping but not when using a 3rd party tool then perhaps there is a bug in your unzip code, not your zip code?